# Can i upload my apk to SD Card instead of internal storage?

Tags: android, android-install-apk

My APK is big, 70 MB.
I don't have any problems when I install it in external storage, but when I upload it to phone before installing, the APK goes to internal storage and my testing phone doesn't have enough space in internal storage and a lot of android phones don't have enough internal space for 70 MB...

Can I upload my APK straight to the SD Card instead of internal storage first?

---

upload mean "upload from my eclipse while runnig , or download from market, apk will go to internal storage but i want apk go to external and start install from external"

Comment: What do you mean by "upload", where are you uploading from and via what?

Comment: upload from my eclipse while runnig , or download from market, apk will go to internal storage  but i want apk go to external and install from external

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can install your app on sdcard by using installation location tag in manifest.. below is more detail

SD-card installation is an optional feature on Android 2.2, is under the control of the developer not the user, and will not affect any applications built prior to Android 2.2.

*Application developers can set the field `android:installLocation` in the root manifest element to one of these values:*

**internalOnly**: Install the application on internal storage only. This will result in storage errors if the device runs low on internal storage.

**preferExternal**: The android system tries to install the application on external storage. If that is full, the application is installed on internal storage.

**auto**: Let the Android system decide the best install location for the application. The default system policy is to install the application on internal storage first. If the system is running low on storage, the application is then installed on external storage.

here is reference doc >> [docs](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2010/07/apps-on-sd-card-details.html)

Comment: i don't have any problem while installing, i can do that 
but i want when download from market or upload from eclipse,
apk go to external storage and start install process from it

Comment: That what i told, You can set these action, if now user install your app it will go on sdcard!! Am i wrong

Comment: ok you are right, files and resources will go to sd card but before start install , eclipse will upload apk to internal storage to start install of apk

Comment: And eclipse will do that. You just need to call adb push "apk" to /sdcard .. you can directly copy your apk file on sdcard.

Comment: Ok but when user download it from market, what the solution of it if user don't have enough space for size of apk ?

Comment: AFAIK, Android System, Market app will show a popup to let user know that not enough space and/or cancel the downloading.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the preferred location for the installation of you app in the amnifest file.

The details of it are given in the Android Developer Docs: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html

Comment: i don't have any problem while installing, i can do that 
but i want when download from market or upload from eclipse,
apk go to external storage and start install process from it

Answer (score 0):

You can set a flag in your AndroidManifest.xml to tell the OS that your app prefers to be installed on the SD Card.

Comment: i don't have any problem while installing, i can do that 
but i want when download from market or upload from eclipse,
apk go to external storage and start install process from it

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the apk from your pc to android phone sd card and then setup. Another thing, the android market does not support an .apk file larger than 50MB.